# Spark: spark-csv partitioning and parallelism in subsequent DataFrames

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

I'm wondering how to enforce usage of subsequent, more appropriately partitioned DataFrames in Spark when importing source data with [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv).

Summary:

- `spark-csv` doesn't seem to support explicit partitioning on import like `sc.textFile()` does.
- While it gives me inferred schema "for free", by default I'm getting returned DataFrames with normally only 2 partitions, when I'm using 8 executors in my cluster.
- Even though subsequent DataFrames that have many more partitions are being cached via `cache()` and used for further processing (immediately after import of the source files), Spark job history is still showing incredible skew in the task distribution - 2 executors will have the vast majority of the tasks instead of a more even distribution that I expect.

Can't post data, but the code is just some simple joining, adding a few columns via `.withColumn()`, and then very basic linear regression via `spark.mlib`.

Below is a comparison image from the Spark History UI showing tasks per executor (the last row is the driver).

**Note**: I get the same skewed task distribution regardless of calling `repartition()` on the `spark-csv` DataFrames or not.

[image: Spark Executor Comparison]

**How do I "force" Spark to basically forget those initial DataFrames and start from more appropriately partitioned DataFrames, or force spark-csv to somehow partition its DataFrames differently (without forking it/modifying its source)?**

I can resolve this issue using `sc.textFile(file, minPartitions)`, but I'm hoping I don't have to resort to that because of things like the nicely typed schema that `spark-csv` provides.

Comment: `df.repartition(n)`?

Comment: @zero323 I can repartition after DataFrame creation just fine, say to 24 partitions, but once the job runs I still see the vast majority of tasks in the job going to only 2 of 8 executors. Any idea why that would still be the case?

Comment: Most likely skewed distribution of values. Can you provide example code you use and maybe some output from UI?

Comment: @zero323 I've updated the question with some more detail. I can't provide data, and it may or may not be skewed values somewhere, but I'm looking for a way to get the same behavior I see via `sc.textFile()` after I do an initial import via `spark-csv`.

Comment: OK, is this preserved when you decrease `spark.locality.wait`?

Comment: @zero323 Changin `spark.locality.wait` from `3s` (default) to `1s` definitely improved the distribution of tasks. I'm assuming this is not very "intelligent" and is a workaround for the fundamental data partitioning issue? Is this just having Spark randomly decide where to send a task, not taking data locality into account?

Comment: @zero323 Also, and I guess as expected, changing the value to `0s` gave an almost perfect distribution of tasks across the executors (and the job completed more quickly).

Comment: It is not but description suggest either some configuration or, what is more likely given low number of input partitions, disproportion between amount of data and amount of resources.

Comment: @zero323 Yeah, that may be (resource or data skew), which is why I need to set the partitions explicitly. To the original question, is there any way to get around Spark leveraging the initial partitions brought in when the DataFrame is first created by `spark-csv`? Re-partitioning at any point, even right after the `spark-csv` `load()` doesn't seem to do much.